# Copy element's attributes to other element in javascript loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have a problem in loop js. I would like to copy `data-icon` value from `.nav` class to  `li` in `#item-control`. Is there anyway easy way to solve it with jquery?

```
<div id="nav-container">
  <ul class="nav">
   <li data-icon="images/1.png">Item 1</li>
   <li data-icon="images/2.png">Item 2</li>
   <li data-icon="images/3.png">Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="item-control">
  <li>Item Control 1</li>
  <li>Item Control 2</li>
  <li>Item Control 3</li>
</div>
```

What I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var a = 1;
    $('#container #nav-container ul.nav li').each(function () {
        var item_control = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('#item-control li');
        item_control.addClass('item' + a);  //this is what I tried before adding data-icon attributes to #item-control li
        a++;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $navItems = $('.nav li'),
    $itemControlItems = $('#item-control li');
$.each($navItems, function(index, el) {
    $($itemControlItems[index]).data('icon', $(el).data('icon'));
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/BRyVL/)

Comment: it doesn't still work, data-icon from .nav li doesn't show in #item-control li

Comment: It does not work, but it works if `.data('icon',` change to `.attr('data-icon',`